# Using variable in array of Tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl

I create a variable called delay

```
set delay [expr ($max-$min)];
```

I want to use it in a array like:

```
set_value/$env(sim_name)/taps  {{0,0,$delay,0,0}}; #double[5]
```

But brace will stop to substitution the value of delay, right？

The fault said is invalid_float or zero element array.

what could I do?

Comment: You're trying to pass more than 2 arguments to a `set` command?

Comment: I edited it from “set value” to “set_value”. It is just one argument.

Comment: Well, now there's no command like that built in Tcl... Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: With the third version of your question, did you intend to have a space after `set_value`, or is the command really that whole word `set_value/$env(sim_name)/taps`?

Comment: Ask your other questions as new questions. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 1):

The outermost braces are for quoting. A good rule for quoting is to use what works. In other words, don't use curly braces if you don't want the behavior of curly braces. If you need to have variables expanded, use double quotes:

```
set_value/$env(sim_name)/taps "{0,0,$delay,0,0}"
```

There's likely another thing wrong with your example. You're calling a command named "set_value/$env(sim_name)/taps", which is a rather unusual looking command name. Are you certain that's what you want to do?

Comment: I'm guessing that it _is_ what he wants; I've seen stuff like that in questions before. (I'm not quite sure which tool they're using, but it seems to exist.)

Comment: It is .scf file, use to setup configures of simulation.

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem. Another thing, if I want to run iterations, using for and incr seems does not work...